# Radio buttons Checked attribute is not working in JsViews

Tags: javascript, jsrender, jsviews

I'm trying to build a page that has a template that contains two radio buttons. I want to make default CHECKED to one of them.

```
<input data-link="checkboxes" type="radio" name="checkboxes" value="true">
<input data-link="checkboxes" type="radio" name="checkboxes" value="false" checked="checked" >
```

and in javascript initialisation

```
checkboxes: true
```

When template renders the radio buttons that have the checked property in the source HTML are not visually checked in the browser.

Comment: why are you doing something on js? you have a plugin? which one?

Comment: i am using Js views but already fixed the issue. Thank you